Interest Rate forward calculation
I have come across two formulas for the forward interest rate computation.These are given below.
1)((Df1/Df2)-1)/(T2-T1)
2) (R2T2-R1T1)/(T2-T1)
I do not understand when should i use which one of the above formulas. Any help would be appreciated!!
Thank you

Option 2 is the linear approximation of Option 1, if R is the term yield;  assume Df(t) = exp(-R(t)t)
Option 1 is always correct
